# Can I add rich text to google sheets note?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, richtext

Can I do this by using a Google API? Assume `note` is the variable of richtext

```
'repeatCell': {
            'range': {
                'sheetId': 0,
                'startRowIndex': start_row,
                'endRowIndex': end_row + 1,
                'startColumnIndex': start_col,
                'endColumnIndex': end_col + 1,
            },
            'cell': {
                'note': note,
                'userEnteredFormat': {
                    'backgroundColor': backgroundColor,
                    'numberFormat': numberFormat,
                },
            },
            'fields': 'note,userEnteredFormat',
        },
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the rich text cannot be used for the note in the Spreadsheet, while it can be used for the cell value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [inserting HTML into pop-ups or notes in google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59343931/inserting-html-into-pop-ups-or-notes-in-google-sheets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tanaike said, Notes (and Comments) only accept plain-text. However, you can fill a Feature Request in [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/).