# How can I display an HTML popup using row data?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, popup

**I would like to display an HTML popup that would display all relevant cells from the currently selected row in Google sheets.**

The code below tries to create an HTML file on my Drive with the relevant row data and then display it as a styled popup.

It's fails to find the file on Drive.

Not sure I fully understand the correct HTMLService to use.

```
function UIPopupVenues() {

var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var sourceSheet=ss.getSheetByName(“Venues”);

var myrow=sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();

var venue=sourceSheet.getRange(“A”+myrow).getValue();

var gigs=sourceSheet.getRange(“B”+myrow).getValue();
var contact=sourceSheet.getRange(“D”+myrow).getValue()+” “+sourceSheet.getRange(“E”+myrow).getValue();
var tel=sourceSheet.getRange(“F”+myrow).getValue();
var notes=sourceSheet.getRange(“G”+myrow).getValue();
var address=sourceSheet.getRange(“H”+myrow).getValue();
var actEmail=sourceSheet.getRange(“J”+myrow).getValue();

var myData=contact;
myData+=’\n’+address;
myData+=’\n’+actEmail;
myData+=’\n’+notes.substring(0,100)+’ …’;

var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(‘FAB’);// folder name on drive
if (folders.hasNext()) {
var folder = folders.next(); //select the folder
folder.createFile(‘frank2’,myData, MimeType.HTML); //create the file
}


// following file on Drive cannot be found    
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(‘https://drive.google.com/file/d/11uoShaX_NxzJMbD6KTaocilO9h9OEMcP’);


// display
ui.showModalDialog(html, ‘Venue’);

}
```

Comment: I would say that this is spam.

Comment: Lemmy - it's not

Comment: @Yunnosch - When I wrote that there was about a paragraph of jam-packed letters that didn't even slightly resemble words. I see that it has since been edited, so it's fine now. If you don't believe me, look at the edit log.

Comment: @LemmyX Fair point. You are right. In that version it deserved all the little "wavy thingies" it got. My mistake to not check the history.

Comment: The file for `HtmlService.createOutputFromFile()` needs to be on the server.  You can crreate it in your script editor.

Comment: You don't need to do a webapp just to display a dialog.  Here's a simple dialog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59345869/7215091

Comment: Thanks Cooper - you helped me :)